# TypeError: provider.send is not a function in anchor

Tags: anchor, web3js, solana, anchor-scroll

I'm looking at this https://book.solmeet.dev/notes/intro-to-anchor written according to the code in the textbook:

`TypeError: provider.send is not a function` when await provider.send()

```js
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { Program } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { AnchorEscrow } from '../target/types/anchor_escrow';
import { PublicKey, SystemProgram, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, Token } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { assert } from "chai";

describe('anchor-escrow', () => {

  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = new anchor.getProvider();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.AnchorEscrow as Program<AnchorEscrow>;

  let mintA = null;
  let mintB = null;
  let initializerTokenAccountA = null;
  let initializerTokenAccountB = null;
  let takerTokenAccountA = null;
  let takerTokenAccountB = null;
  let vault_account_pda = null;
  let vault_account_bump = null;
  let vault_authority_pda = null;

  const takerAmount = 1000;
  const initializerAmount = 500;

  const escrowAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const payer = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate(); 
  const mintAuthority = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const initializerMainAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  const takerMainAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  it("Initialize program state", async () => {
    // Airdropping tokens to a payer.
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
      await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 10000000000),
      "confirmed"
    );

    // ⚠️ An error has occurred here
    await provider.send(
      (() => {
        const tx = new Transaction();
        tx.add(
          SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            toPubkey: initializerMainAccount.publicKey,
            lamports: 100000000,
          }),
          SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            toPubkey: takerMainAccount.publicKey,
            lamports: 100000000,
          })
        );
        return tx;
      })(),
      [payer]
    );
});
```

then run `anchor test`

```js
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/yjy/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
Error: Function _ZN13anchor_escrow9__private8__global8exchange17hb34dfff05db149f5E Stack offset of 4096 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 0 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.34s


Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

Running test suite: "/Users/yjy/Documents/Code/solana/anchor-projects/anchor-escrow/Anchor.toml"

yarn run v1.22.18
warning package.json: No license field
$ /Users/yjy/Documents/Code/solana/anchor-projects/anchor-escrow/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 'tests/**/*.ts'


  anchor-escrow
    1) Initialize program state
    ✔ Initialize escrow
    ✔ Exchange escrow state
    ✔ Initialize escrow and cancel escrow


  3 passing (598ms)
  1 failing

  1) anchor-escrow
       Initialize program state:
     TypeError: provider.send is not a function
      at /Users/yjy/Documents/Code/solana/anchor-projects/anchor-escrow/tests/anchor-escrow.ts:45:20
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (tests/anchor-escrow.ts:28:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `send` doesn't exist, but you can use `sendAndConfirm` if you want to confirm the transction too, or `sendAll` if you just want to send.  That takes an array of Transactions, so you can do:

```
        const tx = new Transaction();
        tx.add(
          SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            toPubkey: initializerMainAccount.publicKey,
            lamports: 100000000,
          }),
          SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
            toPubkey: takerMainAccount.publicKey,
            lamports: 100000000,
          })
        );
        await provider.sendAll([{tx, signers: [payer]}]);
```